# I can't access the new files I make on my root folder in the terminal "no such file or directory"

Tags: shell, files

When I make a new directory, I can see it when I type `ls` in blue letters highlighted in green but when I try to access it it says "no such file or directory". There's another file in there that I can access but not the new ones I create.

```
root@CityWalk:~# cd ~/testing 
root@CityWalk:~/testing# ls 
1 
root@CityWalk:~/testing# mkdir file 
root@CityWalk:~/testing# ls 
1   file 
root@CityWalk:~/testing# cd ~/file 
-bash: cd: /root/file: No such file or directory 
root@CityWalk:~/testing#
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Paste a screenshot please & what do you call "to access" files... (listing them/opening them (mention the application)/change their properties/& so on?

Comment: If it's command line stuff you're using, please DO NOT post a screenshot. Instead, copy and paste the text. Use `{}` to format it as code.

Comment: root@CityWalk:~# cd ~/testing
root@CityWalk:~/testing# ls
1
root@CityWalk:~/testing# mkdir file
root@CityWalk:~/testing# ls
1  file
root@CityWalk:~/testing# cd ~/file
-bash: cd: /root/file: No such file or directory
root@CityWalk:~/testing#

Comment: Notice the tilde `~` in the last issued command. The directory `file` was created under `testing`.  I suppose it doesn't exist a file directory named `file` under the root directory.

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing here so I have two options.

1. You might have created the folder without giving yourself permission. run this with the path to directory:

   ```
   sudo chmod a+rwx /path/to/file
   ```
2. You might have created with root but you're trying to access with your normal user. Open it with `sudo`.

   ```
   sudo cd <directory>
   ```

Comment: Second option is a no-op; you cannot `sudo cd ...`

Comment: And the first option would be `EPERM` not `ENOENT` as in the question.

Comment: you are correct about the Sudo cd. Thank you for letting me know.